# Php web service receiving wrong arguments

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-studio

```java
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    String email = args[2];
    String password = args[1];
    String name = args[0];

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    if(email.length() > 0)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);

    return json;
}
```

When I add username as `"abc"` and password as `"1"`, the string that will be passed to `index.php` is `abc1` for username and `1` for password.

[image]

I would like to access data (login/sign up) using Android with PHP service. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can i post full code?

Answer (score 0):

Check value of name after this statement. It looks like input value is passed incorrectly.
String name = args[0];